# FireBaseInstanceId service does not get registered

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to run demo given [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging). The problem is whenever app tries to register instanceId, it say "background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE, retry in 320s" and then when I print token, it says token is null. I tried changing `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT`instead of `INSTANCEID_EVENT` and other solution that were previously asked on stackoverflow, but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase won't run without Google Play Services, so check if they are available.

Comment: I have already installed google play service, but still it does not work

Answer (score 5):

When running on the emulator, use an image with the Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the solutions provided by [@srivAbhishek001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37452711/4968879) and [@Levent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511370/4968879) and still face the same issue, Kindly check if you have added the Internet permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Sometimes something so obvious becomes the main culprit.

P.S: - It happened with me.