# Unable to subscribe to topic Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
'''public void subscribeToTopic(String topic){
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    String msg = "subscribed to topic \""+topic+"\"";
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        msg = "msg_subscribe_failed";
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, msg);

                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}'''
```

Logcat

**E/FirebaseMessaging: Topic operation failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry Topic operation.**

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by MANY potential issues, including files in the wrong directory, lack of internet connection, outdated Google play packages, and missing in the manifest.

I suggest checking out all the answers here: [FirebaseCloudMessaging : FirebaseInstanceId background sync failed - SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38583278/2301161)

and let's debug from there.

Comment: Thanks the issue was of because of Lack of internet Connection.