# Firebase realtime database not working anymore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using Firebase's realtime database for a while now on my app (java), but today it stopped working. I chacked other posts from this site and nothring really helped.

It doesn't save my data, not even parts of code that used to save fine.

- Checked the status on the [website](https://status.firebase.google.com/), everything seems fine.
- My database rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

- I replaced the google-services.json just in case something of the database changed somehow, but it has not helped.
- The code that I have been using were like this:

```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference().child("characters/2/name");
  mRef.setValue(most_val_q);
  mRef.push();
```

- Checked the Firebase section in Tools to see if it disconnected, but it shows as connected.
- Checked the build.gradle to see if it was a version issue of sorts? It said there was a new verison and all, changed it to the new one, but still doesn't work. So I put the old one, just in case.

And... I checked many things. Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something went wrong?

Comment: For an example of what Alex refers to, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up with a listener as Alex Mamo suggested on a comment, and it did give me an error. Turns out it was the google play services of the phone I was using for testing.

Also had connection issues with said phone.

Here is the post that helped me:
[FirebaseCloudMessaging : FirebaseInstanceId background sync failed - SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583278/firebasecloudmessaging-firebaseinstanceid-background-sync-failed-service-not)

Thank you all in the comments!!